# Weak law of large numbers for epsilon sequence that tends to 0

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Assume a $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ fulfills a weak law of large numbers, i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$P\left(|\tfrac{1}{n}S_n - \mu| > \epsilon\right) \rightarrow 0$$
Does there exist a sequence $(\epsilon_n)_n$ with $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ such that
$$P\left(|\tfrac{1}{n}S_n - \mu| > \epsilon_n\right) \rightarrow 0$$
holds? Or do I need to make further assumptions about the $X_i$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and it really has nothing to do with law of large numbers.

**Lemma**: Suppose $Y_n$ are random variables with $\mathbb{P}(Y_n>\epsilon)\to 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a sequence $\epsilon_n\downarrow 0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y_n>\epsilon_n)\to 0$.

*Proof*: For every $m\geq 1$, there exists $N_m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y_n>2^{-m})<\frac1m$ for all $n\geq N_m$.  So WLOG $N_{m+1}>N_m$, and choose $\epsilon_{N_m}=\epsilon_{N_m+1}=\dots=\epsilon_{N_{m+1}-1}=2^{-m}$.  Then $\mathbb{P}(Y_n>\epsilon_n)<\frac1m$ for all $n\geq N_m$, hence the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

For convergence in probability, by Chebyshev's inequality, an upper bound on the probability is
$$
P(|\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu|>\varepsilon_n) <\frac{Var S_n}{n^2\varepsilon_n} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n \varepsilon_n}
$$
Since second moment is finite, as long as
$$
n \varepsilon_n \to \infty
$$
the ratio converges to $\mu$.